# Does SSL pinning work with WKWebView

Tags: ios, ssl, wkwebview

I read that there is an issue in SSL pinning with WKWebView.
Along with this, SSL pinning is not possible with self-signed certificate.
Can anybody revert with your observation for this, if possible please provide related content URLs or source code chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it worked well. Its straightforward. Although I am still not able to alter the request but thats the another story.

Comment: Hey @kuldip, I'm stuck in the same issue. So I have a url that can only be accessed using SSL Pinnning. All i have is a self-signed certificate file. What should I do to make it work.